# fibonacci c-Programm with array

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a C program that outputs the fibonacci numbers using an iterative function. I want to use an array which containing the Fibonacci numbers
The program gives me the wrong fibonacci values, I cannot see any mistake

Please help
here is my programm:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int fibonacciL(int unsigned value){
    int i;
    const int MAX = value;
    int fibo[MAX];
    
    fibo[0]=0;
    fibo[1]=1;
    
        for(i=2;i<value+1;i++)
        {
        fibo[i]= fibo[i-1] + fibo[i-2];
        return fibo[value];
        }
    }
    
    int main(){
    int value;
    printf("Iterativ Fibonacci\n");
    printf("Enter a Number:");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    printf("For the number %d the value is: %d\n",value,fibonacciL(value));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You allocated the array `fibo` one element less than required.
- You returned `fibo[value]` before calculating that.

```
int fibonacciL(int unsigned value){
    int i;
    const int MAX = value;
    int fibo[MAX+1]; /* allocate one more element so that fibo[value] become available */
    
    fibo[0]=0;
    fibo[1]=1;
    
    for(i=2;i<value+1;i++)
    {
        fibo[i]= fibo[i-1] + fibo[i-2];
    }
    return fibo[value]; /* move this to right place */
}
```

Comment: ouuu i overlooked that, sorry and Thank you for the quick response